# How do I pluck unique values from one Model and use them to map to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Message model that refers to many records with a user_id key. How do I pluck only unique values for this key and then map them to a User model where id (user_id) is the key?

Comment: Let me see if I understand: So you have a `Message` model that `belongs_to` user and a `User` model which `has_many` messages? What is it that you actually want to do with these two models?

Comment: See below, Mori has the right idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user_ids = Message.select('distinct(user_id)').map(&:user_id) 
messaged_users = User.where(id: user_ids)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks, Mori.

Answer (score 0):

`pluck` is more efficient than `select`.  Select will return a relation object and create ruby objects when you map.

```
user_ids = Message.pluck(:user_id) 
messaged_users = User.where(id: user_ids)
```